# Dynamic Height of ReactRootView when embedded inside android native view

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

Trying to add a ReactRootView to my existing layout which looks like this

```
ReactRootView contentView = new ReactRootView(context);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.view_container);
contentView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, "MyComponent", null)
container.addView(contentView, -1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

With the above setup, my reactview never gets rendered, since the height is always 0.
I have to explicitly provide the height to my layout as -

```
container.addView(contentView, -1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, 200));
```

How does ReactRootView handles the layout params when embedded inside a android native app ?

PS: Apologies for cross post did try to raise this issue here :
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13476

Comment: Did you find out @duskandawn ?
I'm having exactly the same issue, and I'm not seeing my ReactRootView.

Comment: I had to do something like this ```new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT))``` for it to show up