# How to make a new ReactRootView within an Expo native module?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-native-module

I'm new to react-native and right now I'm trying to make a new react-native app using the Expo framework. As part of my app, I want to show a bar that displays over the screen even when my app is not active. (I know that display overlays are only possible on Android at the moment.) I can't find any expo package that allows me to render stuff as a display overlay, so it looks like I need to write my own native module to allow me to interface with Android's display overlay mechanisms.

Thus, I made a new native module based on Expo's [tutorial](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/native-module-tutorial/), and added a new foreground service to handle the display overlay. Within the service, I made a new `ViewGroup` and added it as a display overlay, as described in [this popular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481226/6854489). That worked successfully and I'm able to see text overlayed on my screen even when my app is not in the foreground.

The next thing I want to do is render a [chip](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Chip/) from `react-native-paper` in my overlay viewgroup. I made a component `MyChip` that's basically a react-native `View` with a `Chip` inside it. Based on the searches I've done, it seems like I need to call `AppRegistry.registerComponent("MyChip", () => MyChip);` to make my custom view available to react-native. From there, I should be able to do something like this to start up a new react-native view from the Android side that would interface with the `MyChip` component in react-native:

```js
ReactRootView contentView = new ReactRootView(context);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.view_container);
contentView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, "MyChip", null)
container.addView(contentView, -1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

^(this code was copy-pasted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43401523/6854489))

Unfortunately, it seems `ReactRootView` is not directly available to import/instantiate within an Expo native module. Thus, I'm wondering whether Expo has its own special way to declare new ReactRootViews from its native modules? Or do I need to add a new dependency in my native module's `build.gradle` file to make it possible to declare a new ReactRootView?